# How to get session list from Redis?

Tags: php, session, redis

My sessions are stored in Redis server https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis

How can I get all session list from the server?

It was pretty easy when I've used file system:

```
preg_grep("/^sess_/", scandir(ini_get("session.save_path")))
```

php.ini:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you save your sessions.
If they are saved after the key pattern `sess:<sid>`, you can fetch all your session keys with `keys sess:*`. Also you should know that `keys` command could cause performance problems and you should avoid using it in production environment.

**Edit**
Since Redis 2.8, you can use command [`scan`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) to incrementally iterate over session keys. Although it's not current in the phpredis lib.

Comment: It is needed to control online users, to change their privileges etc.
I've added configuration of php.ini to show sessions saving method.
So it will be used on production server too

Comment: @brigantaggior The [docs](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#php-session-handler) says session key prefix "defaults to PHPREDIS_SESSION:", so in the default case you may use "keys PHPREDIS_SESSION:*" to retrieve all the  session keys. Or using phpredis "$allKeys = $redis->keys('PHPREDIS_SESSION:*'); "  https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#keys-getkeys

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count of session keys you can use the EVAL method with a Lua function.

```php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$count = $redis->eval('return table.getn(redis.call("keys", "PHPREDIS_SESSION:*"))');
```

I explain [Redis Sessions in PHP with Kohana](http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2014/03/17/redis-sessions-in-php-with-kohana/) if you want more detail. Here is our dashboard for managing Redis keys:

[image: Redis Dashboard]

Comment: keys command is not recommended to be used in the production environments.